# Objective-C macro starting with @

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Is there a way to create a macro starting with @ in Objective-C?

```
#define @wself __weak typeof( self ) wself = self
```

Gives the error *Macro names must be identifiers*